# CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I know that there are few questions with answers with the same title, but I couldn't find my answer there.
I am getting this error when I moved my code from my other computer. On the other computer the application was working fine. I tried to debug the code without success.

```
Line 45: BeginContext("~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml", 0, 57, true);
Line 46: 
Line 47: WriteLiteral   ("\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
Line 48: 
Line 49: EndContext("~/Views/_ViewStart.cshtml", 0, 57, true);
```

Comment: there are literally *hundreds* of questions regarding this error.  Have you tried **any** of the fixes from any of them, like using `@` at the beginning of your string?

Comment: Thank you. In front of which string? When I tried to debug it , it is hitting this code in the controller "public ActionResult Index() {return View();}  And it is erroring out.

Comment: Can you paste more code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding @ symbol like that :

```
WriteLiteral   (@"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\");
```

This is one way of escaping a string. You can check the [String Literals documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: Thank you. I know how to escape a string. I found the line specified line and modified it and I still have the same error. Without any changes the code was working fine on my other computer.